# ReactJS Tutorial: Where does <Square/> come from?

Tags: reactjs

[In this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html):

`<Square/>` is used here:

```js
    class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
 }
```

But where does `<Square/>` Html Element come from?
In the CSS of the tutorial code, there is indeed a "square" class. However, I then would expect a regular html element (for example a div) to have a class attribute. Furthermore  is capitalized while the css class is not. So I don't understand how this `<Square/>` Markup can work.

Comment: It is defined [in the following snippet](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props).

Comment: There is a snippet right below which defines the Square component. That component renders a button, which is an html element.

Comment: what snippet?
It simply loads the tutorial page, more specifically at the point where I took my own snippet. If the "<"Square/"> element is created there, then I dont understand how. Indeed the class "Square" is set up there, but I havent learned so far that creating a react Component automatically creates a new HTML element?

Comment: Read on a bit more. There is a second snippet.

Comment: Sry, I do know those snippets, but all I can achieve by reading them is drawing conclusions which aren't backed up by any reliable. That's why I posted this question, to get a reliable explanation of whats going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a class `Square` means it's available for use in your React JSX markup in the same scope. Don't confuse JSX with HTML though, they are completely different things. Read more about it here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html